# How do I perform crud operations on the ngMaterial's $mdSidenav?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

Im not able to figure out how do I perform crud operations on the side nav?

I want to populate and update the data from the service.

I have this following controller in the js file.

```
.controller('SideNavCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log, shareDataService) {

.controller('RightCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log, shareDataService) {
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the ng-model, heres' the example below:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label for="testInput">Commentside</label>
    <input type="text" id="testInput" {{desserts.count}} md-autofocus="" value="some comment5">
</md-input-container>
```